# Removing item from list in c++

Tags: c++, hash

hello everyone I am writing a code for hash table and I want to right a delete function for deletion of some string values in the list.

```
void Hash::remove(string word)
{

  int i,flag=0;

  list<string>::iterator it;

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)

  {

   for(it=hashTable[i].begin();it!=hashTable[i].end();it++)

   {

   if(word==*it){

   hashTable.erase(it);

   break;

   }

  }

 }

}
```

But when I compile got an error: 
 error: request for member ‘erase’ in ‘((Hash*)this)->Hash::hashTable’, which is of non-class type ‘std::list > [10]’

I cannot understand this. 
please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Use `hashTable[i].erase(it)` instead of `hashTable.erase(it)`.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems you want to remove all elements that match `word`. Not sure why you are using two loops and a `break` statement. You can use [Erase Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to efficiently remove elements from a container.

In C++11, you can try -

```
hashTable.erase( std::remove( std::begin(hashTable), 
                              std::end(hashTable),
                              [word](const std::string& str){ return str == word;} ), 
                              std::end(hashTable) );
```